# Constructing dbus-send query for Stoping GObject MainLoop

Tags: bash, bluetooth, dbus

I've found example how to stop MainLoop through dbus-send here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34860020/2838794 ,but I'm having hard time figuring out which variables to use for stopping bluez simple-agent on raspberry. https://gist.github.com/keaton-freude/acf87f4b8635d5e3db65cbe01a25e9a2

Example query is set like this:

```
dbus-send --session --type=signal --dest=com.example.StopLoop /com/example/StopLoop com.example.StopLoop.Stop
```

with such info:

```
OPATH = "/com/example/StopLoop"
IFACE = "com.example.StopLoop"
BUS_NAME = "com.example.StopLoop"
```

if i have this info:

```
BUS_NAME = 'org.bluez'
AGENT_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Agent1'
AGENT_PATH = "/test/autoagent"
```

how should i set up the query?
This one gives:

```
dbus-send --session --type=signal  --print-reply --dest=org.bluez.Agent1 /test/autoagent org.bluez.Agent1.Stop
```

gives me an error

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```